# SL40PropertyGrid Button property

Tags: silverlight, propertygrid

I am working with Silverlight property grid (http://slg40.codeplex.com/). I would like to put "Button" as property in this grid and implement the "click" functionality of this button.

Main task is: There is workspace(schema) with objects, properties of object are shown in grid, some of objects have their own schema as a property. I want to show this in grid when the button is clicked.

Now only simple types can be shown in grid. If I add complex type it shows result of "ToString()" and small button. By the way this can be a solution but I can't override Click of this button.

Maybe someone had already solved such task?

Comment: What is the exact problem that you're having? That you can't handle the Click event, or that you can't display complex types in the grid?

Comment: Exact problem is that i can't handle Click event. To display complex type like Button in grid i need to add code in source of SLPropertyGrid but i don't want to do it for some reasons.